# Como pegar link dentro do textarea?

Tags: jquery

No meu textarea tem isso:

```
<Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO><img src='exemplo/imagens/exemplo.png' width=200; height:200; /><Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO />
```

E através do jquery quero pegar usando $('textarea').text();
Mas só que não vem nada.

Comment: Utilize `$('textarea').val();` para capturar o valor do `textarea`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o valor visto que há conteúdo em seu `<textarea>`... use `match()` para retornar um `{Array}` de partes encontradas de acordo com a condição de busca.

```js
let msg = $('#x').val()

let subStr = msg.match("src='(.*)'");

console.log(subStr[1])
```

```css
textarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<textarea id="x">
   <Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO>
       <img src='exemplo/imagens/exemplo.png' width=200; height:200; />
   <Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO />
</textarea>



<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```